# How to extract stan code from rstanarm object

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, stan, rstanarm

Is there a possibility to extract the stan code used for the MCMC sampling in rstanarm?

I would like to compare my own parametrisation of a model and prior choices to the one used in rstanarm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can execute

```
library(rstanarm)
example(example_model)
rstan::get_stanmodel(example_model$stanfit)
```

to see the Stan code or look at it on [GitHub](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstanarm/tree/master/src/stan_files). However, it was not intended to be read by humans and is not particularly readable due to the `#include` statements and the large number of options supported.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'm aware that the models in rstanarm are not intended to be human readable, it's more for learning than for practical use.